# wikidata query how to filter the type of information founds

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, wikidata

I want to find all the informations about Roger Federer(Q1426):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?entity ?entityLabel WHERE {
    wd:Q1426 ?p ?entity.
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language" [AUTO_LANGUAGE],fr".}
}
```

What I want is:

```
wd:Q233306      Mirka Federer
wd:Q1061233     L'Équipe Champion of Champions 
......
```

but what I got is someting like this:

```
wds:q1426-A2132D11-FBBD-44BE-8807-D792797A0F75  
statement/q1426-A2132D11-FBBD-44BE-8807-D792797A0F75
Federer-Express    Federer-Express
ரொஜர் பெடரர்   ரொஜர் பெடரர் 
.......
```

How can I filter the types that I don't want??

Comment: Add `[] wikibase:directClaim ?p` to your query. Is it what you want? See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format

Comment: So by "I want to find all the informations about", you mean "I want to find some of the information about"? It's not clear what info you do want, so we can't be clear about how to get only that and not the stuff you don't...

Comment: I want to find all the named entities which are related with Roger Federer(Q1426)

Comment: @Stanislav Kralin   yes, you are right.  Thanks.  But i always have a problem that how can we determine the right named entity according another named entity,  exemple: when we have  Roger Federer(Q1426) and Wimbledon(in London Q736742) and  Wimbledon(in USA Q736742), how can we use wikidata to get the right relation(Roger Federer, the Wimbledon in London)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i get your right, but i think you query should be like this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?entity ?entityLabel WHERE {
wd:Q1426 ?p ?entity.
?entity rdfs:label ?entityLabel . filter(lang(?entityLabel)="fr")}
```

This also works on other sparql endpoint, which have no special wikidata features.